# How to call a regular function in a callback handler

Tags: python, aiogram

How to call a regular function in a callback handler

there is a menu function:

```
async def menu(message: types.Message):
    user_stat = db.get_user_stat(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer(f"<b>Your ID: {user_stat[0]} Name: {user_stat[3]}</b>", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.main_markup)
```

there is a callback:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == 'back_to_menu':
        await menu(call.message) <- How to call it correctly?
```

Throws an error: IndexError: list index out of range

How to call menu function in callback handler

Comment: What does the value of `user_stat` look like?

Comment: def get_user_stat(self, tg_id):
        with self.db:
            db_result = self.sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tg_id = ?", [tg_id]).fetchall()
            result = list(*db_result)
            return result

Comment: You are sure that this list always has 4 elements?

Comment: yes⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: This seems not to be the case, based on the error you are reporting.

Comment: Just found out that after callback returns an empty list